# EventMachine read and write files in chunks

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm using EventMachine and EM-Synchrony in a REST API server. When a receive a POST request with a large binary file in body I receive it in chunks, writing that chunks to a Tempfile, not blocking the reactor.

Then, at some point, I need to read this file in chunks and write that chunks to a definitive file. This is working, but it blocks the reactor as expected, and cant find a way to make it work without blocking.

I call this function at some time, passing to it the tempfile and new file name:

```
def self.save(tmp_file, new_file)
   tmp = File.open(tmp_file, "rb")
   newf = File.open(new_file, "wb")
   md5  = Digest::MD5.new

   each_chunk(tmp, CHUNKSIZE) do |chunk|
     newf << chunk
     md5.update chunk
   end

   md5.hexdigest
end

def self.each_chunk(file, chunk_size=1024)
  yield file.read(chunk_size) until file.eof?
end
```

I've been reading all other similar questions here at StackOverflow, trying to use EM#next_tick, which is perhaps the solution (not so much EM experience) but cant get it to work, perhaps I'm placing it in the wrong places.

Also, I've tried EM#defer, but I need the function to wait for the read/write process to complete before it returns the md5, as in my main file, after call this function I do a database update with the return value.

If someone can help me on this I would be grateful.

## EDIT 1

I need that the save function only returns after complete the files read/write, as in the caller function I'm waiting for the final md5 value, something like this:

```
def copy_and_update(...)
  checksum = SomeModule.save(temp_file, new_file)
  do_database_update({:checksum => checksum}) # only with the final md5 value
end
```

Comment: `new` is the name of a class method. So unless this is a module, that could be one bug. Change it to something like `new_file` and test it.

Comment: Whell, its just in this code sample, I'm not using that variable names.

Comment: OK. I just thought that that might be the problem, as the smallest problems can show up as the biggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject something in there to break it up:

```
def self.each_chunk(file, chunk_size=1024)
  chunk_handler = lambda {
    unless (file.eof?)
      yield file.read(chunk_size)


     EM.next_tick(&chunk_handler)
    end
  }

  EM.next_tick(&chunk_handler)
end
```

It's kind of messy to do it this way, but such is asynchronous programming.

Comment: Hi, many thanks! I think this solves the read problem, but what about the write part (newf << chunk)? Its blocking the reactor.

Also, I've found that the file is being successful copied but the #save returns the md5 variable after the first iteration, so the md5 being returned is the md5 of the first chunk, as it does not wait for the copy process completion. I've updated the first post (EDIT 1), so it should be more easy to help.

Comment: I don't know that there's a built-in way to channel read and write activity through the EventMachine handler. The best approach is to keep your blocking calls short or at least infrequent. In this case the OS should handle buffering of writes and insulate you from IO issues.